# Trigram distance operations in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fuzzy-search, trigram

I'm currently trying to use the pg_trgm operations `%` and `<->`.
The GIN Indices on the columns are already available, but I can't find the sqlalchemy equivalent to the previously mentioned operators.

What would be the best approach to solve this problem, except writing a pure text query.

A simple example query would be:

```
tag = test
tag_subq = session.query(sticker_tag.file_id, f'sticker_tag.name <-> {tag}'.label(distance)) \
    .filter(f'sticker_tag.name % {tag}')) \
    .filter('distance' < 0.3) \
    .subquery("tag_subq")
```

The query above is obviously not working, and the select and filter string are just placeholder to visualize what I intend to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use the [Operators.op()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.Operators.op) method; this generates whatever operator you need:

```
sticker_tag.name.op('<->')(tag)
sticker_tag.name.op('%%')(tag)
```

The percent operator is doubled up to escape it because %foo or %(foo) syntax is used by python dbapi to insert parameters into the query.

Answer (score 6):

For people who are using Postgres, it's possible to use `similarity` to do so instead.

NOTE: Do remember to install the `pg_trgm` extension in your Postgres first: `CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;`

Here's an example in using SQLAlchemy:

```py
# ... other imports
from sqlalchemy import and_, func, or_

def search_store_product(search_string: str) -> Optional[list[Product]]:
    try:
        return session.query(Product).filter(
            or_(
                func.similarity(Product.name, search_string) > 0.6,
                func.similarity(Product.brand, search_string) > 0.4,
            ),
            and_(Product.updated_on >= datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=5)),
        ).order_by(Product.created_on).limit(20).all()

    except ProgrammingError as exception:
        logger.exception(exception)
        raise

    finally:
        session.close()
```

Comment: Postgres doesn't use indexes for functions. It uses indexes only for operators and `similarity(name, str)` will be very slow. it is better using `Product.name.op('%>')(word)`

Comment: @Goshanull your example works good, I'm not sure what kind of operator is "%>".

Comment: @MarkMishyn There is a list of pg_trgm operators https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested, I did some tests comparing the `%` method and the `similarity(...) > x` method and there is a significant speed up using `%`. Over 10x in some cases.

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE name % 'foo';
```

is way faster than

```
SELECT name FROM x WHERE similarity(name, 'foo') > 0.7;
```

So I recommend only using the `similarity(..)` function in the `SELECT` statement if it's relevant to your query. Like this:

```
SELECT name, similarity(name, 'foo') FROM X WHERE name % 'foo';
```

But you need to set `pg_trgm.similarity_threshold` before using `%` because the default is 0.3 which in my opinion is way too fuzzy and slow for most applications. So r-m-n's answer is preferable, **just remember** to set `similarity_threshold` every session!

**In SQL Alchemy that'll be something like this**:

```
db.session.execute('SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.7;')
items = Model.query.filter(Model.name.op("%")(name)).all()
```

Comment: Did you create a GIN or GIST index on the column you're searching? According to the docs (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-INDEX), "The index will be used to make this [similarity] a fast operation even over very large data sets."