# Fast string search in PostgreSQL table with slightly erroneous input

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sqlalchemy, full-text-search

Assume I have a `user` table in PostgreSQL with columns

```
first_name (PK)
last_name (PK)
email
```

There are now millions of users in it. One user has the record

`(John, Smith, john.smith@gmail.com)`

Now I search for him and enter erroneously `Johny Smit`.

How can I still find the record and this really quick?
Is that possible with sqlalchemy as well?

Comment: possibly related: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Soundex

Comment: Among millions of users, `(first_name, last_name)` can hardly be unique. Revisit the design of your base table before optimizing the index strategy.

Comment: It is an example, so we can assume that for a second. In reality, you would be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [*trigram*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigram)-based indexing and search included in the [`pg_trgm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-INDEX) extension: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/uhBd9K3Y)

```sql
create extension pg_trgm;
create index trgm_idx on my_table using GiST ( first_name gist_trgm_ops
                                              ,last_name  gist_trgm_ops);
```

```sql
select * from my_table 
where    first_name % 'Johny' 
  and    last_name  % 'Smit' 
order by last_name <->'Smit'
        ,first_name<->'Johny'
limit 5;
```

| first_name | last_name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Smith | john.smith@gmail.com |

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Limit (cost=0.28..8.31 rows=1 width=119) (actual time=19.341..19.353 rows=1 loops=1) |
| Output: first_name, last_name, email, ((first_name <-> 'Johny'::text)), ((last_name <-> 'Smit'::text)) |
| -> Index Scan using trgm_idx on public.my_table (cost=0.28..8.31 rows=1 width=119) (actual time=19.337..19.348 rows=1 loops=1) |
| Output: first_name, last_name, email, (first_name <-> 'Johny'::text), (last_name <-> 'Smit'::text) |
| Index Cond: ((my_table.first_name % 'Johny'::text) AND (my_table.last_name % 'Smit'::text)) |
| Order By: ((my_table.first_name <-> 'Johny'::text) AND (my_table.last_name <-> 'Smit'::text)) |
| Planning Time: 1.364 ms |
| Execution Time: 19.416 ms |

1. In a real-life scenario it won't be as fast as this because I just buried `John Smith` under a pile of 100k random `uuid`s.
2. You will have to tweak your similarity target and still probably search for a number of best matches and somehow pick out of those - there could be many people with names that also match your search.
3. You might want use an expression index that merges the two fields so that you can deal with just one search phrase and one resulting similarity metric, instead of having to resolve two.

```sql
drop index trgm_idx ;
create index trgm_idx2 on my_table 
   using GiST ((first_name||' '||last_name) gist_trgm_ops);
```

```sql
prepare find_john_smith_using_pg_trgm(text) as 
select *,$1 as search_phrase
        , (first_name||' '||last_name)<->  $1 as "<->"
        , (first_name||' '||last_name)<<-> $1 as "<<->"
        , (first_name||' '||last_name)<<<->$1 as "<<<->"
        , word_similarity(first_name||' '||last_name,$1)
        , strict_word_similarity(first_name||' '||last_name,$1)
from my_table 
where    (first_name||' '||last_name) % $1
order by (first_name||' '||last_name)<->$1
limit 5;

execute find_john_smith_using_pg_trgm('Johny Smit');
```

| first_name | last_name | email | search_phrase | <-> | <<-> | <<<-> | word_similarity | strict_word_similarity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Smith | john.smith@gmail.com | Johny Smit | 0.4285714 | 0.38461536 | 0.4285714 | 0.61538464 | 0.5714286 |
| Johan | Smittson | johan.smittson@gmail.com | Johny Smit | 0.6315789 | 0.6111111 | 0.6315789 | 0.3888889 | 0.36842105 |

```sql
execute find_john_smith_using_pg_trgm('Johny');
```

| first_name | last_name | email | search_phrase | <-> | <<-> | <<<-> | word_similarity | strict_word_similarity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Smith | john.smith@gmail.com | Johny | 0.6923077 | 0.6363636 | 0.6923077 | 0.36363637 | 0.30769232 |

```sql
execute find_john_smith_using_pg_trgm('Smitt');
```

| first_name | last_name | email | search_phrase | <-> | <<-> | <<<-> | word_similarity | strict_word_similarity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Johan | Smittson | johan.smittson@gmail.com | Smitt | 0.6875 | 0.6666666 | 0.6875 | 0.33333334 | 0.3125 |
| John | Smith | john.smith@gmail.com | Smitt | 0.6923077 | 0.6363636 | 0.6923077 | 0.36363637 | 0.30769232 |

4. If you do keep them separate, you can establish priorities, and for example order by a weighted average of the two - it's safe to assume the match on `last_name` has some priority over the match on `first_name`, especially since last names aren't altered as often (diminutives, abbreviation, nicknames, second names, etc.).

Comment: many thanks for your reply. Assume I have an input form, where a user can either put in just "Johny", "Smit" or "Johny Smit", i.e., it can be quite unstructured. How would I do that?

Comment: I added an edit addressing exactly that: you can merge the fields with an expression index, or try to check the phrase against the fields separately and apply weights to the similarities/distances you obtain that way. You can even try to always check the whole phrase against both fields combined, the whole phrase against one field, then separately against the other, then try to split it and again compare the parts. Depends on how far you want to go with this

Comment: Many thanks for this, it helps a lot. I still have two questions. 1. Do you have an idea of how to implement it with sqlalchemy? 2. Would you use GIN or GIST indices for such queries?

Comment: Create both, benchmark them, see how big they get, how fast they perform and whether you're interested in [things GiST can do that GIN can't](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-INDEX). Here's [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-indexes.html) comparing them. And be sure to also take a look at [Levenshtein in `fuzzystrmatch`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/fuzzystrmatch.html#FUZZYSTRMATCH-LEVENSHTEIN) mentioned by Gord Thompson in the comments.

Comment: As to the sqlalchemy part: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43870442/5298879) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52967464/5298879) looks useful.